# Concatenate multiple join sqlalchemy python with different foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following issue, i need to convert the following query into python's sqlalchemy orm:

```
SELECT parts.model_num, 
       ptemp_objects.ptemp_id, ptemp_objects.type, ptemp_objects.area, ptemp_objects.text, ptemp_objects.x, ptemp_objects.y, ptemp_objects.width, ptemp_objects.height, ptemp_objects.font, ptemp_objects.font_size, ptemp_objects.alignment, ptemp_objects.bold, ptemp_objects.italic, ptemp_objects.display_order,
       ptype_areas.x, ptype_areas.y, ptype_areas.name, ptype_areas.width, ptype_areas.height, 
       paper_types.name, paper_types.width, paper_types.height, paper_types.left_margin, paper_types.right_margin, paper_types.top_margin, paper_types.bottom_margin,
       print_images.path 
FROM parts
JOIN prints
ON prints.part_id = parts.id
JOIN ptemp_objects
ON prints.ptemp_id = ptemp_objects.ptemp_id
JOIN ptype_areas
ON ptemp_objects.area = ptype_areas.id
JOIN paper_types
ON ptype_areas.ptype_id = paper_types.id
LEFT JOIN print_images
ON ptemp_objects.type = print_images.id
where prints.part_id = 879 and parts.model_num="BD854-20-YN-125-BN";
```

I have been trying with this:
session.query(Table1, Table2, Table3).select_from(Table1).join(Table2).join(Table3).all()
but i dont know how to build this in python's sqlalchemy nor how to declare it with so many foreign keys.

I am a beginner using this orm, i've been reading sqlalchemy's documentation but i have not been able to understand it well nor i have not found any solution to build this query. It would be great if you could help me to build this and a bit of explain also would be good.

Thanks!

I am using:

- Windows 10 Professional.
- Python 3.8.8.
- Visual Studio Code.
- SQLAlchemy 1.4.22

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the way to perform many joins into python's sqlalchemy,
basically i performed this code in python:

```
query = session.query(Parts.model_num, Parts.description, PtempObjects.text,PtypeAreas, PrintImages).select_from(Parts)\
                                                .join(Prints,Prints.part_id==Parts.id)\
                                                .join(PtempObjects,Prints.ptemp_id==PtempObjects.ptemp_id)\
                                                .join(PtypeAreas,PtypeAreas.id==PtempObjects.area)\
                                            .join(PrintImages,PrintImages.id==PtempObjects.type, isouter=True)\
                                                .filter(Prints.part_id==879,Parts.model_num=="BD854-20-YN-125-BN")
```